# Alfresco webscript: AJAX, JSON

Tags: json, ajax, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I've successfully created a webscript to that returns a JSON response. See below:

get.js file:

```
// search for folder within Alfresco content repository
var folder = roothome.childByNamePath("PATH");

// validate that folder has been found
if (folder == undefined || !folder.isContainer) {
   status.code = 404;
   status.message = "Folder " + " not found.";
   status.redirect = true;
}

// construct model for response template to render
model.folder = folder;
```

get.json.ftl:

```
{"corporates" : [
     <@recurse_macro node=folder depth=0/>
     ]
}

<#macro recurse_macro node depth>
     <#list node.children?sort_by(["properties","name"]) as child>
          {
          "Name" : "${child.properties.name}",
          "URL" : "${child.url}",
          "serviceURL" : "${child.serviceUrl}",
          "shareURL" : "${child.shareUrl}",
          "ID" : "${child.id}",
          "Type" : "${child.typeShort}"
          },
          <#if child.isContainer>
          {
               <@recurse_macro node=child depth=depth+1/>
          }
          </#if>
     </#list>
</#macro>
```

This returns JSON cleanly (woohoo!), but I would like to grab the JSON from a second webscript using AJAX.

Currently, I am utilizing a typical AJAX call in my second webscript's get.html.ftl file like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit-button').click(function(e) {

  // Avoid to trigger the default action of the event.
  e.preventDefault();

  // Actions declared here...
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'html',
      url: 'PLACEHOLDER_URL_PATH',
      success: function(data) {

        // Shows the result into the result panel.
        $('#alfresco-result').html(data);
        alert('Done.');

      },
      error: function(data) {

        // Shows the result into the result panel.
        $('#alfresco-result').html("ERROR");
        }
    });
});
})
```

My question is why the AJAX call doesn't work when I use dataType: 'json'?

I would like to parse through the JSON in my AJAX call and turn it into html (e.g. an html list), but it's not accepting the JSON dataType as an acceptable input.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's coming back from the AJAX call when you look at the response in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: Hey @JeffPotts, thanks for the reply. I ended up realizing that my JSON webscript wasn't building a valid JSON response (whoops!). The AJAX call works perfectly after creating a valid JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use POST Webscript Call using ajax like this and pass your jsonObject

> dataObj:"yourJsonObject",

to dataObject

```
Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonPost(

{
            url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "sample/mypostwebscript",

            dataObj:"yourJsonObject",

            successCallback: {

                            fn: function(res){

                               alert("success");

                               alert(res.responseText);                                                                                            

                            },

                            scope: this

            },

                            failureCallback:

                            {

                               fn: function(response)

                               {

                                              // Display error message and reload

                                              Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt(

                                              {

                                                             title: Alfresco.util.message("message.failure", this.name),

                                                             text: "search failed"

                                              });                                          

                               },

                                   scope: this

                                }

});

},
```